# How to use spark window function as cascading changes of previous row to next row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to use window function to calculate current value based on previous value in dynamic way

```
    rowID | value
------------------
     1    | 5
     2    | 7
     3    | 6
```

Logic:

```
If value > pre_value then value
```

So in row 2, since 7 > 5 then `value` becomes 5.
The final result should be

```
    rowID | value
------------------
     1    | 5
     2    | 5
     3    | 5
```

However using `lag().over(w)` gave the result as

```
    rowID | value
------------------
     1    | 5
     2    | 5
     3    | 6
```

it compares third row value 6 against the "7" not the new value "5"

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: @fromSAS2Spark - Is your value column already sorted in ascending order? or do you need the smallest value to be appear in the row. i.e where ever it find small it should fill that smallest.

Comment: @GoutamPradhan Thank you. I do not want to fill with minimum, I want to fill with previous value that may have been updated. Example here is very simple but in reality I have 32 row maybe middle 3 only need change

Comment: i think you should use udf. your logic could be dynamic for each row, window functions cant do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.show()
#exampledataframe
+-----+-----+
|rowID|value|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    5|
|    2|    7|
|    3|    6|
|    4|    9|
|    5|    4|
|    6|    3|
+-----+-----+
```

Your required logic is too dynamic for window functions, therefore, we have to go **row by row updating our values**. One solution could be to use normal python `udf` on **collected list** and then explode **once `udf` has been applied**. If have relatively small data, this should be fine.(**spark2.4** **only** because of `arrays_zip`).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def add_one(a):
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
       if a[i]>a[i-1]:
           a[i]=a[i-1]
    return a
udf1= F.udf(add_one, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
df.agg(F.collect_list("rowID").alias("rowID"),F.collect_list("value").alias("value"))\
  .withColumn("value", udf1("value"))\
  .withColumn("zipped", F.explode(F.arrays_zip("rowID","value"))).select("zipped.*").show()

+-----+-----+
|rowID|value|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    5|
|    2|    5|
|    3|    5|
|    4|    5|
|    5|    4|
|    6|    3|
+-----+-----+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

Better yet, as you have groups of 5000, using a **`Pandas vectorized udf( grouped MAP)`** should help a lot with processing. And you **do not have to collect_list** **with 5000 integers** and **explode** or use **pivot**. I think this should be the optimal solution. `Pandas UDAF available for spark2.3+`

**GroupBy** *below is empty, but you can add your grouping column in that.*

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def grouped_map(df1):
   for i in range(1, len(df1)):
        if df1.loc[i, 'value']>df1.loc[i-1,'value']:
           df1.loc[i,'value']=df1.loc[i-1,'value']

   return df1
df.groupby().apply(grouped_map).show()

+-----+-----+
|rowID|value|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    5|
|    2|    5|
|    3|    5|
|    4|    5|
|    5|    4|
|    6|    3|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you. this was my very before last option as actual size of the problem is approx. 5 million rows grouped in 5000. I wasn't so sure how memory utilization will work. My last option was to use pivot and convert these rows into columns then apply similar logic. I do not know either if that can work. I will give both of them a try. Thanks a lot again for confirming that window function can't be used

Comment: @fromSAS2Spark I have updated with a pandas user defined aggregate function which basically using vectorized operations on groups of spark data. i think it will significantly out perform all other options, do try it

Comment: how you guarantee that data is ordered, should I do explicit orderby

Comment: both udfs dont require ordering, they can be applied as is. if u meant after the udf, then that is up to you